# C++ Graphics Equivalent In OBJ-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, graphics, core-graphics

I am about to start development on small project that will use the graphics object in C++ for it's main purpose.

I am also planning on making a Mac OSX version so my question is:

What would the OBJ-C equivalent be for something like.

graphics->DrawString();

Probably nothing so simple and I'm guessing CoreGraphics but have no idea how to do it.

Thanks

EDIT: As has been pointed out to me, my question should be:

What are the Obj-C library equivalents of .Net's system.drawing and how would I do something like DrawString()

Comment: C++ has no "graphics" object, as far as I know.

Comment: @SigTerm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142058.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure Microsoft API is unlikely to have a direct equivalent on a Mac.

Comment: @AshleyStaggs: That's not "c++". That's .NET framework, which has very little to do with C++, because it is not a part of C++ programming language. I'd suggest to drop .NET and switch to Qt 4. It is supported on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: @AshleyStaggs  What sigTerm said is correct.  C++ does not have a graphics object. That sort of functionality is provided by libraries.  What you have pointed to is a routine from the .Net 4 graphics library `system.drawing`, thus supporting his statement.    You have mixed up terminology from the language (C++) and the library (system.drawing) and thus asked a question that is technically nonsensical. The correct way to ask your question is "What are the Obj-C library equivalents of .Net's `system.drawing` and how would I do something like `DrawString()`".

Comment: ah, I understand now. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

> graphics->DrawString();

That's not C++. This is .NET framework, which has very little to do with C++, because (thankfully) it is not a part of C++ programming language. C++ has no classes/functions to deal with graphics or fonts.

Since you want to do cross-platform development, I'd suggest to drop .NET, and switch to Qt 4. [Qt 4](http://qt.nokia.com/) is cross platform GUI framework supported on Linux, Windows and Mac OS. I'm not sure about using it with Obj-C, but I think Mac OS should have a C++ compiler.